# Can WebDav access be configured on Jetty?

Tags: tomcat, jetty, webdav

I'm trying to get WebDav access configured on Jetty, but I'm unable to find any documentation or any working examples specific to Jetty.  So I've tried to retrofit WebDav access for Tomcat unsuccessfully by adding the below servlet config to Jetty's webdefault.xml and placing catalina.jar in Jetty's lib/ext directory

Can anyone point me to working example or should I be doing more to get Tomcat's WebDav access working on Jetty?

```
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>webdav</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.WebdavServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>debug</param-name>
                <param-value>0</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>listings</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>

            <init-param>
                <param-name>readonly</param-name>
                <param-value>false</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </servlet>    

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>webdav</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/sites/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webdav</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sitesedit/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Have you looked at Apache Jackrabbit which provides Webdav?  I'm not in a position to recommend it, but it has a [servlet](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/components/jackrabbit-jcr-servlet.html) for use in a web application.  There's an example of this being used with Jetty [here](https://github.com/mnimer/server-embedded-jetty-jackrabbit).

Answer (score 1):

There is an old project called [Webdav Servlet Project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/webdav-servlet) in SourceForge, 
here is a [fork](https://github.com/ceefour/webdav-servlet).
There is also a most recent project called [WebDav Nio Adapter](https://github.com/cryptomator/webdav-nio-adapter) based on Apache JackRabbit Servlet, suggested by @df778899